# YOLO V3 Video Stream Object Detection

Tags: windows, opencv, python-3.7, object-detection, yolo

i'm using YOLOv3 in detecting objects in a live video camera with OpenCV
but i got this error

> error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:677: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type:  in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'

Comment: Please include more information. Maybe something is wrong the yolo cfg file. Also `readNetFromDarknet` function takes `*.cfg` file as first parameter and `*.weights` file in second parameter.

Comment: @B200011011 Thanks I was passing Weights file firstly and the Config. file in the last, it's fixed.