# Open-Cv dnn error for python while using Yolov3. Using open-cv ver(4.2.0)

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

***cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:677: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type:  in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream***

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load Yolo
path =r"D:\yolov3-coco"
weight = path+r"\yolov3.weights"
cfg = path+r"\yolov3.cfg"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(weight ,cfg )
classes = []
with open(path+"\coco.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
print(cfg)
print(weight)
print(classes)



cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have already used the command `net= cv2.dnn.readNet(weights,cfg)` but it did not work i have also gone to https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights and downloaded the weights and config files and have put them in a folder called yolov3-coco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be passing `*.weights` first and `*.cfg` later. If takes `*.cfg` first, then the darknet `weights` file. Reference for `readNetFromDarknet`,

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gafde362956af949cce087f3f25c6aff0d

This problem is similar to,

[YOLO V3 Video Stream Object Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209761/yolo-v3-video-stream-object-detection#comment108336972_61209761)

Comment: net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(cfg ,weight )
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:677: error: (-212:Parsing error) Unknown layer type:  in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStreamI get same error

Comment: Changing to `net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(cfg, weight)` and file path works on my machine. I have tested with https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/, yolov3 weights and config without any error on OpenCV 4.3.0.

Comment: This change did not seem to have effect on my computer i think my version of opencv may be incompatible or the library may be incomplete . I made sure to download the latest version of open-cv  but i see no avail. So i have used tensorflow lite interpreter for the yolov3 instead

Answer (score 2):

For me it were the wrong files. I was trying it in google colab with version 2.5.0 of tensorflow. The following files worked:

!wget "https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights"

!wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjreddie/darknet/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg"

!wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjreddie/darknet/master/data/coco.names"

Comment: This worked for me. Looks like the cfg and weights can be incompatible with each other if downloaded from different projects. Thanks Rajesh!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yolo3-coco cfg and weight do not match so Unknown layer type error.

Comment: I downloaded it from a prescribe link and i checked it , can you prescribe an links that you may know of

Answer (score 0):

**Path for yolov3.weights,yolov3.cfg is not proper so you can pass path directly where they are stored**

`net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov3-coco/yolov3.cfg", "yolov3-coco/yolov3.weights")`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `OpenCV --version 5`. My error was solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

ı had trouble problem like this. Just check your code path and make sure where cfg,weights are,open main folder and work under the main folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).